# Alter the cruisecontrol log with XSLTLogPublisher

Tags: ant, logging, cruisecontrol

We build our project from CruiseControl.
We have a ant script running some exec commands, and the output of this is placed in the CDATA part of that message, and its priority is set to "info".

Now I have created an XSL that modifies this priority depending on the CDATA output, so it creates a new logfile that I want CruiseControl to use.

I tried to do this by using XSLTLogPublisher tag like this

```
<xsltlogpublisher directory="${log.dir}" outfilename="${logname}" xslfile="${transform}" />
```

But it doesn't seem to work. No error is logged from cruisecontrol no changes are done in the log file, might it be that cruisecontrol have problems transforming its own log, or are the publishers invoked after the actual log is published as a web page?

Can anyone provide some sort of solution to my problem?

Are there any way to change the log file cruisecontrol uses?

Would it be possible to alter the log file from the ANT script instead?

Answer (score 0):

The CruiseControl configuration element is called [`<xsltlogpublisher>`](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#xsltlogpublisher). You have `<xsltlogtransform>`. Was it a typo here in SO or in your configuration?

EDIT:

`<xsltlogtransform>` doesn't accept an attribute called 'outfile'. There seems to be 'outfilename' instead. Is it again a SO typo? :)

Comment: And how do you know what is the build log file name? I thought the `${logname}` was some special variable provided by CruiseControl, which refered to build log file name. But I can't see it.

Comment: The attribute was a typo, the ${logname} is wrong I found it referenced on a web page, and is as Grzegroz say not in CruiseControl, but it does illustrate what I want to do.